# Patch function error while using collection

Tags: list, sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have written this code:
Clear(colSaveData);
ForAll(Gallery4.AllItems,Collect(colSaveData,{Title: "New Entry",PanId:TextInputCanvas4.Value,Name:TextInputCanvas5.Value,Types:ComboboxCanvas5.Selected.Value,Scheme:TextInputCanvas7.Value,Amount:TextInputCanvas8.Value,Date:DatePickerCanvas2.SelectedDate}));
Patch('MF Users',colSaveData)
Error is in patch function

Do not recognize colSaveData

Answer (score 0):

While you call Patch('MF Users',colSaveData) , here you have to carefully check all columns names and their order, those should be exact as per 'MF Users' table/SharePoint list